# Sortable table with extra header row

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Is it possible to disable `sortable` behaviour on the first header row?

```
<table class="ui sortable table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        Header
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th class="ascending sorted">Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
</table>
```

Currently it behaves like this: 
[image]

The header cursor is a pointer and the background changes onblur/onFocus.

Comment: Might not be a fix for your solution, but a workaround could be to create a segment or menu and attach it to the top of your table instead of creating a second header.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add javascript for handling the sorting or you can use a popular dependency like [dataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/semanticui.html) for table sorting, searching, filtering etc. which comes with Semantic UI integration.

To sort a table, you then can simply call an instance of dataTable like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

You should check out that reference. It has a pretty straightforward example and usage guide.